# Getting conflict between two magento extensions how to solve this

Tags: magento

I have already installed [manufacturer_brand_logo extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo-7813.html) in my magento now i am trying to install [customer feedback extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/feedback-1959.html)  but i was not able to install it.i am getting the error during installation.How to fix this and make the two extension to work..

Comment: Can you show your error here?

Comment: Checking dependencies of packages

CONNECT ERROR: Package 'bc_feedback' is invalid
'./app/code/local/Bc/Bcall/etc/adminhtml.xml' already exists   (I am getting the error like this when i am trying to install) @Amit Chaudhary

Comment: Checkout the below solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all files are not downloaded. Check your theme folder and compare it with downloaded extension from http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are trying to install the module from Magento connect right?

So you have two option to fix this issue.

1. Download the module source code using the extension key from http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and manually put the files and folder in your directory, except Bc_Bcall module.
2. Delete the `app\etc\modules\Bc_Bcall.xml` and `app\code\local\Bc\Bcall` folder and install the module form Magento connect.

Hope this will help you!